# Bidirectional TLinkPropertyToField Bindings

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I have a TLinkPropertyToField Binding a TRadioGroup (Custom) to a Field using the ItemIndex property but I don't know why it doesnt pass the changes to the DataSet

Code:

```
auxLink := TLinkPropertyToField.Create(aOwner);
auxLink.Component := aOwner.FindComponent(aField.FieldName);
auxLink.ComponentProperty := 'ItemIndex';
auxLink.DataSource := BindSource;
auxLink.FieldName := aField.FieldName;
auxLink.Active := true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `TLinkPropertyToField` does not naturally provide the requested functionality. [See documentation:](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.Bind.Components.TLinkPropertyToField)

> **Tip:** The user input to this component is not monitored using an
>   observer.

In other words the link is one way only.

You need pass the changes to `ItemIndex` manually or subclass the `TLinkPropertyToField` adding observer functionality. I doubt it is worth doing.